# Excel help: sum numbers if within date range

Tags: excel, excel-formula, date-range, sumifs

I have a spreadsheet of expenses, sorted by categories in columns `C` through `P` (eg, "rentals" in column `C`, "catering" in column `D`, etc). The date is in column `A`.  I want to find the sum of all expenses in columns `C:P`, but only those where the date is between a certain range.  Here's what I tried:

```
=SUMIFS(C:P,A:A,">=1-Feb-2018",A:A,"<=28-Feb-2018")
```

but I get a `#VALUE!` error.  I think it is because `C:P` is a different size selection than `A:A`?  It works if I do

```
=SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,">=1-Feb-2018",A:A,"<=28-Feb-2018")
```

Is there another formula that will work without using

```
= SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,">=1-Feb-2018",A:A,"<=28-Feb-2018")
 +SUMIFS(D:D,A:A,">=1-Feb-2018",A:A,"<=28-Feb-2018")
 +SUMIFS(E:E,A:A,">=1-Feb-2018",A:A,"<=28-Feb-2018")...
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you can get it to work with a `SUMIFS`, but here's a `SUMPRODUCT` version:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(C:P * (A:A <= DATE(2018,2,28)) * (A:A >= DATE(2018,2,1)))
```

---

You could also create a helper column, say `Q`, that sums `C:P` and use your `SUMIFS` on that.

```
=SUMIFS(Q:Q, A:A, ">=1-Feb-2018", A:A, "<=28-Feb-2018")
```

Comment: Because `sumproduct` performs array like operations, full column references should be avoided as it can lead to excessive unnecessary calculations.

Answer (score 1):

This is because `1-Feb-2018` is not recognised by Excel as a date - it will be giving a `#Name?` error inside the formula, as it's not even a String (`">=""1-Feb-2018"""`))

1st February 2018 is treated by Excel as the number `43132` (Number of days since 31/12/1899), but is then Formatted as `d-mmm-yyyy` to *display* as `1-Feb-2018`.  You can either:

1. Type the number: `">=43132"`
2. Add 0 to a string version to convert it: `">=(0+""1-Feb-2018"")"`
3. Use the `DATE` function: `">=" & DATE(2018,2,1)`

All 3 of these work with `SUMIFS`, like so:

1. `=SUMIFS(C:P, A:A, ">=43132", A:A, "<=43159")`
2. `=SUMIFS(C:P, A:A, ">=(0+""01-Feb-2018"")", A:A,
   "<=(0+""28-Feb-2018"")")`
3. `=SUMIFS(C:P, A:A, ">=" & DATE(2018,2,1), A:A, "<=" &
   DATE(2018,2,28))`

Personally, I recommend method 3